# Repeated regex replacements with overlapping lookbehinds

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I want

```
oy 1 x 1 x 1
   1 x 1 x 1
```

to become

```
oy 1 y 1 y 1
   1 x 1 x 1
```

(basically, replacing `x` by `y` if the line starts with `oy`, reusing `y`).

I have tried

```
echo "oy 1 x 1 x 1" | sed -E "s/(o(.)(.*))x/\1\2/g"
echo "oy 1 x 1 x 1" | perl -pe "s/(?<=o)(.)(.*)x/\1\2\1/g"
echo "oy 1 x 1 x 1" | perl -pe "s/o(.)(.*)\Kx/\1/g"
```

but each replaces only the last occurence.

These non-greedy variants

```
echo "oy 1 x 1 x 1" | perl -pe "s/(?<=o)(.)(.*?)x/\1\2\1/g"
echo "oy 1 x 1 x 1" | perl -pe "s/o(.)(.*?)\Kx/\1/g"
```

replace only the first occurence.

What else can I try?

Comment: `perl` doesn't support variable length lookbehind, otherwise regex only solution would be possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/\<(o(.) .*)x/\1\2/;ta' file
```

If there is a word `oy` where `y` is any character, match that character and replace any `x`'s throughout the rest of the line with it.

Comment: It seems to me the pattern should be `^(o(.) .*)x`, it is said the whole line must start with `oy`.

Comment: Would you care to explain what  the differences to my trials are? It seems the relevant parts are simply `:a;` and `;ta`.

Comment: @bers they form a loop, as long as the substitution succeeds, `t` will branch to label `a`.. this is similar to `perl -pe 'while(s/^o(.).*?\Kx/$1/){}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it's a habit/fault of mine that tries to pre-empt the users next question by parametrising the solution. You can of course surround the  solution with`/\<oy\>/{...}` if you so please.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/x/substr($_,1,1)/ge if /^o/' ip.txt
oy 1 y 1 y 1
   1 x 1 x 1
```

- `/^o/` if line starts with `o`
- `substr($_,1,1)` second character of input line as replacement string
- `e` flag to allow Perl code in replacement section

If the string to replace may match the first two characters, then:

```sh
$ echo 'oy 1 o 1 o 1' | perl -pe 's/o/substr($_,1,1)/ge if /^o/'
yy 1 y 1 y 1
$ echo 'oy 1 o 1 o 1' | perl -pe 's/..\Ko/substr($_,1,1)/ge if /^o/'
oy 1 y 1 y 1
```

I'm not sure if using `substr` on `$_` while the `s` command modifies `$_` is dangerous. If so, you can use these alternatives:

```sh
perl -pe '$c=substr($_,1,1); s/x/$c/g if /^o/'

# courtesy @ikegami
perl -pe 's/x/$c/g if ($c) = /^o(.)/'
```

Comment: `perl -pe's/x/$c/g if ($c) = /^o(.)/' ip.txt`